# Regex lookaround does not work with quantifiers in SAS

Tags: sas, regex-lookarounds

I have a table similar to this:

```
Data have;
text = 'insurance premium'; output;
text = 'insur. premium'; output;
text = 'premium. insur aa'; output;
text = 'premium card'; output;
text = 'sales premium'; output;
Run;
```

My task is to select all transactions that contain the word premium, but do not contain the word insurance or a form thereof (e.g. insur, ins. etc.). I read up on how to use lookaround expressions in regex and wrote the following expression:

```
/(?<!ins[a-z.]*\s)premium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s)/i
```

The expression seems to work on testing websites such as https://regexr.com/, but when I run the code below I get an error in SAS:

```
Data want;
Set have;
re = prxparse('/(?<!ins[a-z.]*\s)premium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s)/i');
flg = prxmatch(re, text) > 0;
Run;

ERROR: Variable length lookbehind not implemented before HERE mark in regex m/(?<!insur[a-z.]*\s)premium(?!.*insur[a-z.]*\s) << 
       HERE /.
ERROR: Variable length lookbehind not implemented before HERE mark in regex m/(?<!ins[a-z.]*\s)premium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s) << HERE /.

ERROR: The regular expression passed to the function PRXPARSE contains a syntax error.
NOTE: Argument 1 to function PRXPARSE('/(?<!ins[a-z'[12 of 45 characters shown]) at line 30 column 6 is invalid.
NOTE: Argument 1 to the function PRXMATCH is missing.
```

As far as I understood there is an issue with the `*` symbols inside the lookaround functions, because the error does not occur if I remove them. Does SAS implement such expressions differently or does it simply not support such expressions?

Comment: You might put the lookahead at the start of the string, and then match the word `premium` 
 like `^(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s).*\bpremium\b.*` https://regex101.com/r/5xUvGw/1

Comment: Why not just use two separate searches? One for premium and a separate one for insurance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `flg = prxmatch(re, text) > 0;` to see if there is a match by checking if the position is `> 0`

You can put the negative lookahead at the start of the string to check for the variations of insurance, and then match the word premium.

```
^(?!.*\bins[a-z.]*\s).*\bpremium\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that on the right is not

  - `.*\bins`  Match a word starting with `ins`
  - `[a-z.]*\s` Optionally repeat matching chars `a-z` or `.` followed by a whitespace char
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `.*\bpremium\b` match the word `premium` in the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NHt811/1)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a lookbehind with a variable width pattern in a PCRE regex. However, you can match and skip substrings you do not need using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs, so you can revamp the regex you have in the following way:

```
prxparse('/ins[a-z.]*\spremium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s)(*SKIP)(*F)|premium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s)/i')
```

Mind that patterns are parsed and searched for from left to right. `ins[a-z.]*\spremium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s)(*SKIP)(*F)|` is triggered first, and if `ins[a-z.]*\spremium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s)` is found, it is skipped. Else, the second `premium(?!.*ins[a-z.]*\s)` alternative comes into play and matches `premium` not followed with `ins` and zero or more letters / dots and a whitespace in other contexts.